# Passing an Object to a Function in C++

Tags: function, c++11, object

I am writing a C++ code that requires an object to be passed to a function.  I have tested the class and functions separately, so I know that there are no problems with them, the problem is instead caused when I try to pass the object to the function.  When I write the function, my Xcode IDE is telling me that it does not recognize the "type" Input_File, which is not a type, but is an object name.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Object {
  // class functions go here
}
void Test_Func(const Input_File *obj)
{
    Object_Value = obj->Object_Value
    std::cout << Object_Value << std::endl;
} 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    Object One;
    Test_Func(&One);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `Test_Func` needs a pointer of `Input_File` type while you pass a pointer of `Object` type.

Try this:

```
void Test_Func(const Object *obj)
{
    auto Object_Value = obj->Object_Value
    std::cout << Object_Value << std::endl;
}
```